# Is there any way to set ID in mock domain object using GORM

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, spock

I have a controller with the following code...

```
def myController(Command command){
   DomainObj obj = command.domain
   if(obj.id) update(obj)
   else createNew(obj)
   ....
}
```

Now I am trying to create my test but when I do

```
@Mock(DomainObj)
...
  DomainObj obj = new DomainObj(id:123L)
```

But the test fails because the ID is not set. I do not have access to the GORM project so changing the domain class (I.E. hasId method) is not a viable option. Is there a way I can set this value in my unit test?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind apparently `obj.metaClass.id = 123` worked even though the IDE was still showing as null

Answer (score 0):

You also can directly set id in the object like this:

```
@Mock(DomainObj)
...
DomainObj obj = new DomainObj(id:123L)
obj.id = 123
```